# how to do C when either A or B has a valid response by rxjs?

Tags: rxjs

Once I get a response from A, whose status is 'success', then do C.
Once I get a response from B, whose code is 0, then do C.

If I use `combineLastest`

```
combineLatest(A,B)
.pipe(
  filter( ([a,b])=> {a.status == 'success' || b.code == 0} )
)
.subscribe(()=>doC());
```

will when B return a invalid response (the code is not 0), but because A had a valid response previously, so it still pass the `filter` and doC() is called? This is contrary to my goal.

If so, what operator I should use?

Thanks a lot

(Here I don't care nad use the data of response from A or B, but if I need use that in `doC`, what operator I should use?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand the problem right, I would proceed like this (see comments for explanation of the code)

```
// you create 2 separate Observables, one with source A and one with souce B,
// representing the streams whose notifications trigger doC()
const source_A = A.pipe(
  filter(a => a.status == 'success')
);
const source_B = B.pipe(
  filter(b => b.code == 0})
);
// then you merge these 2 Observables to create a new Observable which notifies when any of these Observables notifies
merge(source_A, source_B).pipe(
  // then you perform doC() when any notification arrives
  // here I use the tap Operator but you can also insert this logic
  // into the subscribe parameter
  tap(value => {
     // here value is either 'success' or 0 depending on whether A or B 
     // are the origin of the notification
     doC()
  })
)
// eventually you subscribe
.subscribe()
```

Comment: @ildvzg68472 It happens often to many people, the first one is me